# cryptozombies(solidity) why using storage instead memory?

Tags: solidity

In a function like `getKitty`, they ([CryptoZombies Tutorial Tool](https://cryptozombies.io)) create a storage kit first and then use fields in the structure. But why not use memory instead of storage? Memory cost less and also be able to use all fields. I wonder why they use storage?

```
function getKitty(uint256 id) external view returns (
    bool isGestating,
    bool isReady,
    uint256 cooldownIndex,
    uint256 nextActionAt,
    uint256 siringWithId,
    uint256 birthTime,
    uint256 matronId,
    uint256 sireId,
    uint256 generation,
    uint256 genes
    ) {
    Kitty storage kit = kitties[id];

// if this variable is 0 then it's not gestating
isGestating = (kit.siringWithId != 0);
isReady = (kit.cooldownEndBlock <= block.number);
cooldownIndex = uint256(kit.cooldownIndex);
nextActionAt = uint256(kit.cooldownEndBlock);
siringWithId = uint256(kit.siringWithId);
birthTime = uint256(kit.birthTime);
matronId = uint256(kit.matronId);
sireId = uint256(kit.sireId);
generation = uint256(kit.generation);
genes = kit.genes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is defined as "external view".
External view functions don't cost any gas when they're called externally by a user since they are not modifying anything on ethereum state.
I got it from delegatecall.com